# Display true and false from SQL Select Query as Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli, checkbox

Current state is this code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['timeStamp'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['what'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['salad'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['tomatoes'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['onions'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['carrots'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['hot'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cheese'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sauce'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

The rows salad, tomatoes, onions, carrots, hot and cheese are saved as true and false, because the users insert them as checkboxes.
What i basically want is to display true or false as checkboxes in the table i'm writing the sql result

Is this somehow possible?
Let me know if you need more code (like the whole php).

Comment: You can use a ternary operator. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have value saved for each of that item as `true` or `false` in db

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['timeStamp'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['what'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['salad']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['tomatoes']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['onions']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['carrots']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['hot']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['cheese']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' " . ($row['sauce']=='true' ? 'checked' :'') . "/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you can simply add a checkbox and set the checked attribute if the value is true as follows

```
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" value="true" ';
echo ($row['salad'])? 'checked' : '';
echo '></td>';
```

Note if you don't want the user to edit it or uncheck it you can add the **disabled** attribute.

Comment: Very cool, thanks! Works :)
And thanks for the tip with the disabled attribute. Gonna need this.